# Divisibility of numbers

Tags: code-golf

## Challenge

HP is doing research in mathematics . After doing lots of research, she struck in a problem . She found four numbers n,a, b and c .Now, She wants to know how many number exists which are less than or equal to n and are divisible by a ,b or c .

## Input :

4 integers denoting `n,a,b and c` separated by space

## Output :

intger which denotes the count of the numbers which are divisible `a,b,c`

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Can you add test cases? Does the count include 0 and negative numbers?

Comment: What are the ranges of the input parameters?

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>72</s> 65 bytes

*Note:* This solution works for *positive* integers:

```python
lambda a,b,c,n:len([x for x in range(1,n+1)if x%a*(x%b)*(x%c)<1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcTBDkAwDADQX@lFstKDOogIX4JDh7GEksVhvn7iHd79PvulVXL9mA457SIgZGkmbY9VzRDBXQEieIUguq2GSQtG7yBmkpuYWfyfseMJ0x28PuBMTQ1xSVxh@gA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```python
lambda n,a,b,c:n/a+n/b+n/c-n/a/b-n/a/c-n/b/c+n/a/b/c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ1EnSSfZKk8/UTtPPwmIk3WBbP0kMAliJ@kna4NF9JP/FxRl5pUopGkYGumY6VjoGBpo/gcA)

By the [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).